# How to get the length of map values flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Map<String, bool> _toDos = {
      'case1': true,
      'case2': false,
      'case3': false,
      'case4': false,
      'case5' : false

    };
```

Say I have a map object like this and I want to get the length of strings that contains "true" values. How do I do so with flutter?

`_toDos.length` gives me the length of the map but I want to get the length of items that contain only "true" values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_todos.values.where((element) => element == true).length

Comment: absolutely nicely written, make it answer and it would be helpful for others developer.